# Discovering tests on provided classpath via LauncherDiscoveryRequest

Tags: java, junit5

I am trying to discover JUnit 5 tests with the help of `LauncherDiscoveryRequest` as [described in the user guide](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#launcher-api). The code I am using looks as follows:

```
LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
    .filters(includeClassNamePatterns(".*"))
    .build();

TestPlan plan = LauncherFactory.create().discover(request);

for (TestIdentifier root : plan.getRoots()) {
    System.out.println("Root: " + root.toString());

    for (TestIdentifier test : plan.getChildren(root)) {
        System.out.println("Found test: " + test.toString());
    }
}
```

Does `LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder` only auto-discover tests on the classpath of the JVM running this code? I tried using the methods `DiscoverySelectors.selectClasspathRoots` and `DiscoverySelectors.selectClasspathResource` as selectors to provide root directories to be searched for test classes. However, I wasn't able to discover any tests. Do the parameters for `selectClasspathRoots` and `selectClasspathResource` have to point to the root directory containing the class files organized by package or do you provide the full path to each test class file?

I tried the following where `/some/dir` represents the root directory containing test class files:

```
File classesDir = new File("/some/dir");
LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
     .selectors(selectClasspathRoots(Collections.singleton(Paths.get(classesDir.toURI()))))
     .build();
```

I had a look at [`LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilderTests.java`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/master/platform-tests/src/test/java/org/junit/platform/launcher/core/LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilderTests.java) but it wasn't very useful in figuring out why my example code doesn't work. How do I best diagnose the issue?

I am using the following dependencies:

- `org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:1.0.0-M3`
- `org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.0.0-M3`

Comment: Some help with someone related ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46329888/discovering-test-with-junit-5-dont-execute-logginglistener-implementation-of-t

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does `LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder` only auto-discover tests on the classpath of the JVM running this code?

Short answer: Yes, the `Launcher` will only auto-discover tests on the classpath of the JVM running the code.

In general, `TestEngine` implementations are responsible for resolving selectors such as the `ClasspathRootSelector` you create via `selectClasspathRoots()`. The Jupiter and Vintage engines will scan the supplied directories for `.class` files and then try to load them using the current thread's context `ClassLoader`. If the latter step fails, the class will be silently ignored.

If you want to discover tests not yet on the classpath, you need to create a new `ClassLoader` and make it the current thread's context `ClassLoader`. The JUnit Platform `ConsoleLauncher` does this, too:

1. [Create custom `ClassLoader`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/r5.0.0-M3/junit-platform-console/src/main/java/org/junit/platform/console/tasks/ExecuteTestsTask.java#L70-L79)
2. [Invoke `Launcher` with replaced context `ClassLoader`](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/r5.0.0-M3/junit-platform-console/src/main/java/org/junit/platform/console/tasks/ExecuteTestsTask.java#L54)

Comment: Thanks for information. That works. It might be worth mentioning those details in the JUnit 5 user guide.

Comment: I've now documented this prerequisite in the Javadoc for `selectClasspathRoots` and `ClasspathRootSelector`: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/commit/2de35be3f5537b4e49a20080125441c9b8376b71

Comment: Great, thx! Doesn't this behavior apply to `selectClasspathResource` as well?

Answer (score 2):

Does LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder only auto-discover tests on the
classpath of the JVM running this code?

No, it can scan every single class in the jvm. You will have to provide at least one selector, but the discovery is done through organized folder/ package structure on the classpath.

Add filter to control what classes to be scanned.

This is from the docs.

> There’s currently the possibility to search for classes, methods, all
>   classes in a package, or even all tests in the classpath.

All the discovery selectors are various ways to reach the test classes.

May be there is little more context, but this is all I can figure out based on docs and running/debugging below tests.

[ClasspathScannerTests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/master/platform-tests/src/test/java/org/junit/platform/commons/util/ClasspathScannerTests.java)

Output

```
Root: TestIdentifier [uniqueId = '[engine:junit-jupiter]', parentId = null, displayName = 'JUnit Jupiter', source = null, tags = [], test = false, container = true]
Found test: TestIdentifier [uniqueId = '[engine:junit-jupiter]/[class:discover.suite.Junit5TestCase]', parentId = '[engine:junit-jupiter]', displayName = 'Junit5TestCase', source = ClassSource [className = 'discover.suite.Junit5TestCase', filePosition = null], tags = [], test = false, container = true]
```

Sample Test Class

```
package discover.suite;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class Junit5TestCase {

    @Test
    public void junitMethod() {
    }

}
```

Below are few examples using different selectors.

```
    //By classpath root
    File classesDir = new File("C:\\Users\\me\\Junit5\\target\\test-classes");

    LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
            .selectors(selectClasspathRoots(Collections.singleton(Paths.get(classesDir.toURI()))))
            .filters(includeClassNamePatterns(".*"))
            .build();

    //By package
    LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
            .selectors(selectPackage("discover.suite"))
            .filters(includeClassNamePatterns(".*"))
            .build();

    //By Class
    LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
            .selectors(selectClass(Junit5TestCase.class))
            .filters(includeClassNamePatterns(".*"))
            .build();

    //By Method
    LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
            .selectors(selectMethod(Junit5TestCase.class, "junitMethod"))
            .filters(includeClassNamePatterns(".*"))
            .build();
```

Comment: help executing tests with LauncherDiscoveryRequest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46329888/discovering-test-with-junit-5-dont-execute-logginglistener-implementation-of-t