# How can I discover tests from packages in another module on a Java project using Junit LauncherDiscoveryRequest?

Tags: junit, package

I tried to check for answers in https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#advanced-topics.

The code works fine for package selection if we want to disocver in same package or down package but it is unable to search for tests if the tests are present in some other package in other module.
Code --> 
LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
                .selectors(
                        selectPackage("com")
                )
                .filters(
                        TagFilter.includeTags(tag)
                )
                .configurationParameters(map).build();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Classdir and selectClasspathRoots(Collections.singleton(Paths.get(classdir.toURI()))) method to pass in selectors to discover tests in entire directory. If tests are present in other module , they will be discovered too.
Use below for Classdir

File classdir = new File("Project Path\ProjectName\target\*");

All the tests present in target folder will be discovered.

Comment: this can't possibly be correct according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41394027/1059372), unless all your paths are loaded into the JVM